# Coroutine problems

Tags: lua, coroutine, roblox

so I'm trying to make a basic GUI animation system in ROBLOX, using individual frames and a loop to put them into an imagelabel.

This is the function:

```
local playAnimation = coroutine.create(function(anim,pos,tank)
    while true do
    local animBase = sp.AnimBase:Clone()
    animBase.Parent = tank
    animBase.Visible = true
    animBase.Position = pos -- line that causes the error mentioned below.
    local frame = 1
    for i = 0, animations[anim]["FrameNum"] do
        frame = frame + 1
        animBase.Image = animations[anim]["Frames"][frame]
        NewWait(.1) --this right here, the wait, interfears with the yield.
        if frame >= animations[anim]["FrameNum"] then
            pos,anim,tank = coroutine.yield()
            break
        end
    end
    animBase:Destroy()
    end
end)
```

There are two main problems with this:
every time it runs, I get this error:

```
20:41:01.934 - Players.Player1.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.Gui-MAIN:65: bad argument #3 to 'Position' (UDim2 expected, got number)
```

Although this error doesn't seem to do anything. (eg. stop the script completely)

The line causing the error is marked with a comment.

I've made sure that pos is correct. I even tried printing it before setting it, it prints the correct thing which is:
{0,120},{0,65}

The other main problem is that I can't resume it after using it once. It can run this line multiple times fine:

```
coroutine.resume(playAnimation,"Cannon Fire",UDim2.new(0,120,0,68-25),tank.Frame)
```

but it won't run:

```
if tank2:FindFirstChild("Ammo") and isTouching(ammoFrame,tank2:GetChildren()[3]) then
    local lastAmmoPos = ammoFrame.Position
    ammoFrame:Destroy()
    coroutine.resume(playAnimation,"Explosion",lastAmmoPos-UDim2.new(0,25-(ammoTypes[type]["Size"].X.Offset)/2,0,25),tank.Frame)
    tank2:GetChildren()[3]:Destroy()
end
```

Yes, the if statement is working fine. ammoFrame is destroyed and so is the third child of tank2. The coroutine just won't resume.

Comment: Regarding the error, it is definitely because you are assigning something else to animBase.Position (your pos argument is not of expected type) - from http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Lua_errors

Comment: As I stated, it the correct type. (UDim2.new)

Comment: And in your yield statement, are you sure that you are having the right order of variables (pos, anim, tank)? Shouldn't it be "anim, pos, tank", as that is the order you are giving them to resume function in your last code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by removing the coroutine completely and wrapping the for loop inside a spawn function.

```
local playAnimation = function(anim,pos,tank)
    local animBase = sp.AnimBase:Clone()
    animBase.Parent = tank
    animBase.Visible = true
    animBase.Position = pos
    local frame = 1
    spawn(function()
        for i = 0, animations[anim]["FrameNum"] do
            frame = frame + 1
            animBase.Image = animations[anim]["Frames"][frame]
            wait(.1) --this right here, the wait, interfears with the yield.
            if frame >= animations[anim]["FrameNum"] then
                break
            end
        end
        animBase:Destroy()
    end)
end
```